# How can I incorporate this callback function to capitalize all the first letters in the values of this object?

Tags: javascript

Write a function that uses your "fixTitle" function to fix each title and return an array of strings where each entry is the fixed title.

```
function fixTitle(str) {
var words = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
}
return words.join(' ');
}
console.log(fixTitle("THE HiSTory of mathematiCS")); // "The History Of Mathematics" 

function bookTitle(arr){
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var key in arr[i]) {
      result.push(bookTitle(arr[i][key]))
    }
  }
  return result;
}


const books = [
  {title: "the midnight sky", author: "Samuel Goodens"},
  {title: "technology In THE age of artificial intelligenge", author: "Lara Del Rio"},
  {title: "never GIVE up", author: "Michelle Li"}  
];
console.log(bookTitle(books)); //["The Midnight Sky", "Technology In The Age Of Artificial Intelligenge", "Never Give Up" ]
```

Comment: ```fixTitle``` function is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that you need to access the `title` property from each object in `books`, you don't need to loop over the keys using a `for..in` loop. Instead, use the `title` key directly and remove the inner loop `result.push(fixTitle(arr[i].title))`. Also make sure you are calling the correct function `fixTitle` in your function, and not `bookTitle`

```js
function fixTitle(str) {
  var words = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
  }
  return words.join(' ');
}

function bookTitle(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(fixTitle(arr[i].title))
  }
  return result;
}


const books = [
  {title: "the midnight sky", author: "Samuel Goodens"},
  {title: "technology In THE age of artificial intelligenge", author: "Lara Del Rio"},
  {title: "never GIVE up", author: "Michelle Li"}  
];
console.log(bookTitle(books)); // ["The Midnight Sky", "Technology In The Age Of Artificial Intelligenge", "Never Give Up" ]
```